# Arrow label on Chemfig image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=2cm, png]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman, danish]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{R'-[9]-[7]-[9](-[7]R'')=[10]O}
\end{document}
```

I just want arrows with letters on to point on each carbon, and one to point at oxygen. I don't know how to do it. Maybe you can help?

Comment: I'm not sure, you want arrows to point to the two Rs and to O?

Comment: @Alenanno To the carbons and to the O :-)

Comment: That does something: `\chemfig{R'-[9]-[7]-[9](-[7]R'')=[10]@{O}O}
\chemmove{\draw[<-] (O) -- + (45:1);}` Unfortunately it doesn't update the bounding box. The [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf) has a lot more examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? It uses the fact that `chemfig`'s formulas are `tikzpicture`s. `chemfig` offers the possibility to give explicite names to the nodes in a formula using `@{name}` (this is explained in the manual). Later one can refer to those nodes in a seperate `tikzpicture`. `\chemmove` simply is a wrapper for a `tikzpicture` with the options `remember picture, overlay`, both of which are explained in the TikZ manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=2cm, png]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{R'-[:30]@{C3}-[:-30]@{C2}-[:30](-[:-30]R'')=[2]@{O}O}
\chemmove[shorten <=2pt]{
  \draw[<-] (C3) --++(0,1) node[above] {carbon} ;
  \draw[<-] (C2) --++(0,-1) node[below] {carbon} ;
  \draw[<-] (O) --++(1,.5) node[right] {oxygen} ;
}

\end{document}
```